# Matrix - Vector - equation

Tags: matrices

why is

$$(x-a)^TH(x-a)= x^THx - 2a^THx + a^THa$$

i would have done it that way:
$$(x-a)^TH (x-a) = (x^TH - a^TH) (x-a) = x^THx - x^THa- a^THx +a^THa$$

Comment: I guess you're in the hypothesis $H^T=H$, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is correct.  But if $x^T Ha$ is a $1\times1$ matrix, then it's a scalar, so it's the same as its own transpose, which is $a^Hx$.  In that case $a^T Hx + x^T H a$ would be the same as $2a^T Hx$.

**PS:**  It's being pointed out by G. Sassatelli, that $H^T=H$ must hold for all this to be true.  I confess I was thinking of $H$ as both symmetric and idempotent, the "hat matrix" denoted by "H" for "hat".  Idempotence is irrelevant to the present problem, but symmetry must be assumed and I should have said so.

Comment: It most likely is the case, but you need $H$ to be symmetric for that identity to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Its equivalent since $x^tHa$ and $a^tHx$ are both scalars so you can take their transpose.